# how to load multiple pages one by one in QWebPage

Tags: qt, pyside, web-crawler, qwebkit, qwebpage

I am trying to crawl news article pages for comments. After some research I found that mostly websites use an iframe for it. I want to get the "src" of the iframe. I am using QtWebKit in Python using PySide. It is actually working but just once. It is not loading other webpages. I am using the following code:

```
import sys  
import pymysql
from PySide.QtGui import *  
from PySide.QtCore import *  
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Render(QWebPage):
  def __init__(self, url):
    try:
      self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    except RuntimeError:
      self.app = QCoreApplication.instance()
    QWebPage.__init__(self)
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
    self.app.exec_()

   def _loadFinished(self, result):
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()
    self.app.quit()


def visit(url):
  r = Render(url)
  p = r.frame.toHtml()
  f_url = str(r.frame.url().toString())
  return p

def is_comment_url(url):
  lower_url = url.lower()
  n = lower_url.find("comment")
  if n>0:
    return True
  else:
    return False

with open("urls.txt") as f:
  content = f.read().splitlines()
list_of_urls = []

for url in content:
  page = visit(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
  for tag in soup.findAll('iframe', src=True):
    link = tag['src']
    if is_comment_url(link):
      print(link)
      list_of_urls += link
pprint(list_of_urls)
```

But the issue is it works only for single iteration and gets stuck.

Also is there any way to save a web page as it is as displayed by the browser (after executing all the javascript etc.)

Comment: The example does not run right out of the box for a couple of reasons. Can you fix it? For example by putting some urls by hand into variable `content`.

Comment: @Trilarion the file "urls.txt" contains some urls of news articles. You can put some urls into it or can make the content list directly by defining here in the program. But that is not the problem. The problem is it is not iterating on the urls. It gets stuck after loading one url till timeout occurs. Contents of "urls.txt" are:
http://ibnlive.in.com/news/promoting-hindi-doesnt-mean-we-are-discouraging-other-languages-mha/480275-62-128.html
http://ibnlive.in.com/news/bjp-backs-rapeaccused-mos-nihal-chand-survivor-claims-threat-to-life/480283-3-239.html